# Conditional probability: Is the equivalence true?

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be a probability measure on a $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$. I want to prove or disprove the following statement:

- for $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ with $0<P(A), P(B)<1$ it is $$P(B\mid A)=P(B\mid \overline{A}) \iff P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

$$$$

I have done the following:

- $\Rightarrow$ :

  It holds that $P(B\mid A)=P(B\mid \overline{A})$.

  By definition of conditional probability we get that $P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$ and $P(B\mid \overline{A})=\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$.

  So, we get the following: 
  $$P(B\mid A)=P(B\mid \overline{A})\Rightarrow \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}\Rightarrow P(B\cap A)=P(A)\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$$

  So, we have to show that $\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}=P(B)$, right?

  Doesn't this hold only when $\overline{A}$ and $B$ are disjoint?

  $\Leftarrow$ :

  It holds that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

  By definition of conditional probability we get that $P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A)}=P(B)$ and $P(B\mid \overline{A})=\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}=\frac{P(B\cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$.

  We want to show that $P(B\cap \overline{A})=P(B)P(\overline{A})$. But how?

Comment: Hint: use $P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap\bar{A})=P(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $P(B|A)=P(B|\bar{A})$, we have

$$\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B\cap\bar{A})}{P(\bar{A})}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)+P(\bar{A})}=P(B),$$

using $P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap\bar{A})=P(B)$, because $(B\cap A)\cap(B\cap\bar{A})=\varnothing$. Therefore we obtain $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. From $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ we have

$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=P(B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(\bar{A}\cap B)}{P(A)+P(\bar{A})}=\frac{P(\bar{A}\cap B)}{P(\bar{A})}.$$

Therefore $P(B|A)=P(B|\bar{A})$. And we also obtain $P(A|B)=P(A|\bar{B})$ similarly. All $3$ statements are equivalent, while $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ looks most symmetric.

$$P(A|B)=P(A|\bar{B})\;\Longleftrightarrow\; P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\;\Longleftrightarrow\; P(B|A)=P(B|\bar{A}).$$

We have shown in probability theory that "$A$ is independent of $B$" is the same thing as "$A$ and $B$ are independent", and is the same thing as "$B$ is independent of $A$".

Comment: How did you get the second = at $$\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B\cap\bar{A})}{P(\bar{A})}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)+P(\bar{A})}=P(B),$$ ? How do we use here the fact that $P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap\bar{A})=P(B)$ ? Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Using $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\;\Rightarrow\;\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ ($b+d\neq 0$).

Comment: @MaryStar, it's the other way $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a-c}{b-d}$. Also we have $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(\bar{A}\cap B)$ and $P(A)+P(\bar{A})=1$.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ Applying [Bayes rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)
$$P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})}=\\
\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(\overline{A})}=P(A)$$
But $P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ from [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), thus $\Rightarrow P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$

$\Leftarrow$ Applying [Bayes rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)
$$\frac{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})}=P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)\cdot P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A)$$
Or 
$$\frac{P(B \mid A)}{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})}=1 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(B \mid A)=P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A}) \Leftrightarrow\\
P(B \mid A)\cdot (1-P(A))=P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})\Leftrightarrow\\
P(B \mid A)\cdot P(\overline{A})=P(B \mid \overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{A})\Leftrightarrow\\
P(B \mid A)=P(B \mid \overline{A})$$

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)