# prove that two events are independent if P(A|B) = P(A| not B)

Tags: probability, independence

Prove that the two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if : $$ P( A|B) =  P(A| \overline{B}) $$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than votes to close and downvotes if you edit the question to include the text (not a link to an image) and show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: You can probably take that as a definition of independence!

Comment: the question asks to prove that if P(A|B) = P(A|not B) holds then two events are independent

Comment: Yeah… we understood. What are your thoughts about it? Don't just link pictures but type it yourself… that makes it much easier for others to answer your question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional probability: Is the equivalence true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520115/conditional-probability-is-the-equivalence-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A|B) = P(A|\overline{B})$ by definition is $$ \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A\cap \overline{B})}{P(\overline{B})} $$ Now  using the fact  $ P(A \cap B) +P(A \cap \overline{B}) = P(A) $ ,we get :$$ P(A \cap B) (1- P(B)) = (P(A) - P(A \cap B)).P(B) \implies  P( A \cap B) - P( A \cap B)P(B) = P(A).P(B) - P(A \cap B).P(B) \implies P(A \cap B) = P(A).P(B) $$
Thus they are independent by definition.

Also intuitively ,  if they are independent, then the conditional probability of $A$ w.r.t $B$ and $\overline{B}$  has to be same as $A$ doesn't depend  whether $B$ has occurred or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you tell me that how P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) do you assume that they are independent ?

Comment: its just comes from the previous equation just cancelling the term $P(A \cap B).P(B)$

Comment: first you did a cross multiplication to get P(A and B).(1-P(B)) = [P(A)-P(A and B)].P(B) this I understand. but at next step I don't know how did you write P(A and B) - P(A and B)P(B) ? is it because you expanded the brackets from previous step, if so then it means P(B) is multiplied inside the bracket ?

Comment: @IqbalHafizi yes i just wrote it  by just expanding.